# Wieso "ihre" Mannschaft?

Tags: sentence-structure, personal-pronoun, address

Heute habe ich diesen Satz irgendwo gelesen:

> Michael, wie oft hat Ihre Mannschaft ein Spiel?

Wieso ist in dem Satz "ihre" und nicht "deine"?

Comment: Ohne mehr über das "irgendwo" zu wissen, wird man da spekulieren müssen.

Answer (score 9):

> **Satz:** *Michael*, wie oft hat *Ihre* Mannschaft ein Spiel?
>
> **Frage:** Wieso ist in dem Satz *Ihre* und nicht *deine*?

Das ist das sogenannte [*Hamburger Sie*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_Sie), bei dem die Person sowohl mit Vornamen (hier *Michael*) angeredet als auch gesiezt wird. Es stellt einen Mittelweg dar zwischen ausschließlichem Duzen oder Siezen wie in den folgenden Beispielen:

> - *Michael*, wie oft hat *deine* Mannschaft ein Spiel?
> - Herr *X*, wie oft hat *Ihre* Mannschaft ein Spiel?
>     
>     <sub>(Hier steht *X* für den Nachnamen von Michael. Ist der nicht bekannt, so lässt man „Herr *X*“ einfach weg.)</sub>

Bekannte Vertreter, die untereinander das Hamburger Sie gepflegt haben, sind beziehungsweise waren [Peer Steinbrück](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_Steinbr%C3%BCck) und [Helmut Schmidt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmut_Schmidt) (vgl. z. B. das Buch [*Zug um Zug*](https://books.google.de/books?id=cjRR7KIHlGAC)).

Comment: Es gibt noch die österreichische Variante, bei der dem Vornamen noch ein "Herr" vorangestellt wird: "Herr Karl".

Answer (score 2):

`Ihre`, nicht `ihre`.  Das macht einen Unterschied: es handelt sich um das zum höflichen Pronomen der zweiten Person, `Sie`, gehörige Possesivpronomen.  Die höflichen Personalpronomen entsprechen denen der dritten Person Plural, werden aber großgeschrieben.

Die Kombination so einer Anrede mit einem Vornamen statt "Herr Sowieso" ist seltener, aber möglich.

---

Andere Interpretation, da kein Kontext gegeben ist: es handelt sich um einen Schreibfehler und sollte `ihre` sein.  Dann kann es sich entweder um das Possesivpronome der dritten Person Plural handeln ("their"), oder des Femininums der dritten Person Singular ("her").